# How to create Dock entries via Terminal in macOS Sierra?

Tags: dock, macos

So I found a command that lets me create Dock entries via Terminal. This was working fine on OS X El Capitan, but not with macOS Sierra.

Any ideas how this can be done with macOS Sierra?

This is sample command that works with OS X El Capitan:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/VLC.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a test in macOS Sierra, I just downloaded the vlc-2.2.4.dmg file and installed VLC to */Applications* via drag and drop to the Applications alias within the installer window.

In Terminal, I ran the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/VLC.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>"; killall Dock
```

Note that I added `; killall Dock` directly after the command line from your question.

As the Dock reappeared, the VLC Dock Tile was present and I then click it. VLC opened as expected.

Comment: somehow when I tried it, it wasn't working

Comment: @mrjayviper, had you used `killall Dock` directly afterward the first time? If not, that is why is didn't work. When modifying com.apple.dock you have to used `killall Dock` directly afterward, either with a `;` when done in the same command line or without it directly after.

Comment: I didn't use killall immediately. But at the end of my script is a killall Dock.

Comment: @mrjayviper, As many of the preferences are loaded to memory at login, then when making a change with `defaults` in this case you need to use `killall Dock` directly after as the system can/will make a changes to the copy in memory and write it back to disk file and thus overwrite what you changed as it was never memory resident. That is possibly/probably what happened to you.

Comment: @user3439894 I had the same situation, and this code works when run from the terminal. However, do you see any reason why it would not run from within a post-installation script in an Installer?

Comment: @Max Wyss, I forget for sure which version of OS X dramatically changed the effective use of the `defaults` command and can only state from my own use and observation that in recent years if `killall` isn't use immediately after the `defaults` command, one risks the modification made being over written by the system. Timing is everything! If it doesn't work for you then you need to find an alternative and or do it differently.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the answer. As mentioned, the code works when entered manually through the terminal, and it does include the killall Dock statement. I am running 10.12, as mentioned in your answer, so I should have the same behavior… I may have to look around for other approaches anyways…

Comment: But how do you add folders and files to the right side of the dock with terminal?

Comment: This command `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Users/pschorn/Downloads/</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'; killall Dock` Adds a folder, but then a pop-up menu doesn't display when you click on it; the folder just opens immediately in a new finder window. Does Anyone know why? How to I make it so that the pop-up menu displays when I click on it @ser3439894 @Max Wyss

Comment: @Peter Schorn, The following example `bash` _command_ creates as **Dock Tile** for the user's **Pictures** folder with _default settings_: `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>file://$HOME/Pictures/</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>15</integer></dict></dict><key>tile-type</key><string>directory-tile</string></dict>"; killall Dock` There are other _keys_ and corresponding _values_ to change the **Sort by**, **Display as** and **View content as** settings.

Comment: @Peter Schorn, This command is equal to the one in my previous comment to you except it has the other _keys_ and corresponding _values_, albeit the _default_ ones: `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>arrangement</key><integer>1</integer><key>displayas</key><integer>0</integer><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>file://$HOME/Pictures/</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>15</integer></dict><key>showas</key><integer>0</integer></dict><key>tile-type</key><string>directory-tile</string></dict>"; killall Dock`

Comment: @Peter Schorn, The **Sort by** _default_ is **Name** and is `<key>arrangement</key><integer>1</integer>`, for **Date Added** it's `2`, **Date Modified** it's `3`, **Date Created** it's `4` and **Kind** is `5`. The **Display as** _default_ is **Stacks** `<key>displayas</key><integer>0</integer>` for **Folders** it's `1`. The **View content as** _default_ is `<key>showas</key><integer>0</integer>`, for **Fan** it's `1`, for **Grid** it's `2`, and **List** is `3`.  BTW These were tested under **macOS High Sierra** and may differ in other version of **macOS**.

Comment: @Peter Schorn, For a _file_ on the right end of the **Dock** use the following while replacing `file:///path/to/file%20name.pdf` with the correct _fully qualified pathname_: `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add "<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>file:///path/to/file%20name.pdf</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>15</integer></dict><key>file-type</key><integer>32</integer></dict><key>tile-type</key><string>file-tile</string></dict>"; killall Dock`

Comment: @Peter Schorn, RE "But does this work for a folder?" Please reread my first, second and third comments to you, as it covers adding  a **Dock Tile** for _folders_ to the right side of the **Dock**. My fourth comment to you cover a **Dock Tile** for _files_ to the right side of the **Dock**. This, my fifth comment to you, should not have been necessary if you took the time to carefully read and try what was posted in my first four comment to you.

Comment: I'm sorry I accidentally skimmed over the part where you discussed adding folders. That was totally my fault. Also, I just used your instructions to add a folder with custom styles!!! You're a godddddammm genuis!!! I just have to ask one more thing: How do I remove the folder I just created?

Comment: @Peter Schorn, RE: "How do I remove the folder I just created?" You can right-click on any **Dock Tile**, except **Finder** and **Trash** and select **Remove from Dock** from the **Options** menu, or click-hold and drag it from the **Dock**.

Comment: I'd like to be able to remove the folder programatically. I'm creating a script that will display any files that have been AirDropped to my computer in a folder on the dock. I've figured out how to use a folder action script to automatically move airdropped files to a folder that I named "AirDrop," and now you've just helped me add it the the dock. The last thing I want to do is make it so that the AirDrop Folder automatically gets removed from the dock when it's empty. I'm sure it'll be easy for me to write code that detects when the folder is empty...

Comment: ... I just need your help creating a command that removes the folder from the dock

Comment: @Peter Schorn, Please keep in mind that in spite of the title of the OP, he's was really interested in just getting a command that used to work in a previous version of OS X/macOS to work in a different version. The question was not meant to be canonical nor was the answer, just a quick answer to resolve his immediate issue. You really should post your own question, however off the top of my head I don't have a programatic answer for you, although I'm sure I could figure it out, but I'm off to sleep.

Comment: Here's a link my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59345726/12394554 Have a good night's sleep. @user3439894